# Could not proxy request /favicon.ico from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

I am trying to create chat app with socket io, react, and node.js. when I run `npm run develop` **or** `cd client npm start` **&** `cd server npm start` I get  `Could not proxy request /favicon.ico from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.` I checked my package.json file in my client directory, and I have the proxy as `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"` I have also tried `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"`. I even have a setupProxy middleWare in my client/src/setupProxy.js:

directory tree:

```
client
  |
   -- package.json
server
  |
   -- index.js
   -- package.json
package.json
```

```
const createProxyMiddleware  = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/**',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3001',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Here is also my package.json in the root level:

```
  "name": "play-date",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "<=14.x.x",
    "npm": "<=6.x.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cd server && node index.js",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i ",
    "develop":  "concurrently \"cd server && npm start\" \"cd client && npm start\" "
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/paulkalait/playDate.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/paulkalait/playDate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/paulkalait/playDate#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "temp-dir": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.7.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

And My Index.js file:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { createServer } from "http";
import cors from "cors";
import * as path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
//routes
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";
import chatRoute from "./routes/chats.js";
import messageRoute from "./routes/message.js";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
//initialize this app
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
//set up body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

//must be above the routes
app.use(cors());

//use middleware for the prefix routes th post routes will be reached bu localhost:3001/posts/ ....
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/chat", chatRoute);
app.use("/message", messageRoute);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
// Serve up static assets
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/images")));

//---------------SOCKET IO LOGIC------------------
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    //react server
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});

let activeUsers = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  //add new User
  socket.on("new-user-add", (newUserId) => {
    //if user is not add peviously
    if (!activeUsers?.some((user) => user?.userId === newUserId)) {
      activeUsers?.push({
        userId: newUserId,
        socketId: socket.id,
      });
    }
    console.log("connected users", activeUsers);
    io.emit("get-users", activeUsers);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    //filter out the user that is trying to disconnect
    activeUsers = activeUsers?.filter((user = user?.socketId !== socket.id));
    console.log("User disconnected", activeUsers);
    io.emit("get-users", activeUsers);
  });

  socket.on("send-message", (data) => {
    const { receiverId } = data;
    const user = activeUsers?.find((user) => user?.userId === receiverId);
    console.log("sending from socket to : ", receiverId);
    console.log("data", data);
    if (user) {
      io.to(user.socketId).emit("receive-message", data);
    }
  });
});
//---------------SOCKET IO LOGIC------------------

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
}
app.get("*", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"),
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(500).send(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"),
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() =>
    httpServer.listen(PORT, () =>
      console.log(`server is running on port: ${PORT}`)
    )
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Do you have a full error + stack trace

Comment: If you have `setupProxy.js` I would suggest you to remove the one from `package.json`, as the first is more robust based on my personal experience, and having two may causes conflicts.